# Link two obj files to bin

Tags: assembly, linker, bin, object-files

In last days I'm playing with bootloaders and assembly language. I have compiled to files into .obj file format. Now I need to link them. Does anybody know with which linker it's possible or can anybody place here link to page with sample? Please help.

Comment: gcc's ld can do this, but if I recall correctly you need to write a special linker script file to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'ld' from GNU toolchain.

Here's a page with all the required linker scripts to properly place the kernel.

http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/Docs/basickernel.htm

First-stage bootloader is a "flat" binary with opcodes. For x86 BIOS-based boot all you have to do is to place the code at 0x7C00 (you know that, I'm sure).